# MySQL: get sum of columns with multiply two columns on behalf of third column

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I am trying to get sum of all rows with multiply two column values with where condition but getting some error of mysql. After try some example i achieve my result but i don't know that is right way or not:

Table: **store_stocks**

[image]

i just want to count the stock qty with amount multiply with qty according to with VAT, with non VAT and total stock.

I just created that query:

```
SELECT sum(qty*sale_price) as total_stock, 
 (select sum(qty*sale_price) from store_stocks where vat_status = 0 and store_id = 8) as non_vat_stock, 
 (select sum(qty*sale_price) from store_stocks where vat_status = 1 and store_id = 8) as with_vat_stock 
 FROM `store_stocks` where store_id = 8 group by store_id
```

and its showing result:

[image]

can any one tell me is there any another way to achieve this, because i think that's query is little bit complicated, each time i am using where in sub query and i also have to implement this query in `laravel eloquent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need subqueries, you can use a condition within the `sum()` to make it summarise the specific records only:

```
SELECT sum(qty*sale_price) as total_stock, 
       sum(if(vat_status = 0, qty*sale_price, 0)) as non_vat_stock, 
       sum(if(vat_status = 1, qty*sale_price, 0)) as with_vat_stock 
 FROM `store_stocks` where store_id = 8 group by store_id
```

You can use a `case` expression instead of the `if()` function as well.

Comment: its showing error 'as non_vat_stock, 
       sum(if(vat_status = 1, qty*sale_price, 0) as with_vat' at line 2

Comment: Missed closing `)` twice. But pls do not just copy-paste a solution, also try to understand it.

Comment: My point was around that tou did not even try to find the source of the error, just pasted back the error message.

Comment: yes i agree with you.. i will keep in my mind next time sir :)